# C++ USB library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, usb, arduino

Is there a library/method for communicating with a microcontroller (Arduino)?

Basically, I need a method of receiving and sending data between the PC and the Arduino. I don't know what library to use, so I'm asking you. The data I'm going to send is little. Maybe 500 bytes back and forth. Everything is happening in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions) 2010, in a console application.

Comment: [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) may be of interest to you

Answer (score 5):

[libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) seems to be one of the best choices in your case. This is a lightweight, widely-used, open-source, cross-platform and well-documented C library.

Answer (score 1):

`termios` also works fine. I've been using it to connect an Arduino to a Raspberry Pi (Linux) via serial link (USB). You could find some useful code snippets [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Boost ASIO works well. Have a look at Stack Overflow question *[Reading messages from a serial port with Boost Asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212835)*. I recently had to write some code for communicating through the serial port, and I used an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) to test it.

If you install the [FTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTDI) driver for your Arduino board, Windows will recognise it as a [COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29), and you can communicate with it as if it is a normal serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [ArduSerail](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/ArduSerial) is a SUPER easy to use C++ library to interface with Arduinos on Windows platforms via USB.

Comment: Add this as a comment